# How to set CRS (coordinate reference system) to new created LAZ file by using WKT?

Tags: python, arrays, lazy-evaluation, qgis, wkt

I am created LAZ file from .npy - file, but there is no CRS inf.

When I am extracting ['data'] from .npz file - X, Y, Z - Laz file is created but not showing me points in QGIS (but present I can printed and see in open 3d module).

Also .npz file contains array ['wkt'] - that has all required info for transformation to specific CRS:
"WKT:
PROJCS["NAD83 UTM 18",GEOGCS["unknown",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26918"]]

Q; How by using python attached wkt  - to header(?) of new created LAZ file to be able to see data on specific CRS (from wkt) on the map in QGIS?

Thank you